# Sub account not work API Soap PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, php

I have a problem to point a subaccount in the PHP SOAP API, where can I make this note?

My Code:

```php
include LOCAL_SYSTEM . 'application/src/Plugins/Exacttarget/exacttarget_soap_client.php';
include LOCAL_SYSTEM . 'application/src/Plugins/Exacttarget/creds.php';

//================================================
// USER | PASS
$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdlExacttarget, array('trace' => 1));
$client->username = $userExacttarget;
$client->password = $passExacttarget;

//================================================
// DATA EXTENSION
$ts = new ExactTarget_TriggeredSend();
$tsd = new ExactTarget_TriggeredSendDefinition();
$tsd->CustomerKey = "test_api_01";

$clientIDObj = new ExactTarget_ClientID();
$clientIDObj->ClientID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

//================================================
// SUBSCRIBER | EMAILADDRESS
$sub = new ExactTarget_Subscriber();
$sub->SubscriberKey = 1;
$sub->EmailAddress = 'test@test.com.br';

//================================================
/*name
Text
254*/
$dadosEXAC1 = new ExactTarget_Attribute();
$dadosEXAC1->Name = "name";
$dadosEXAC1->Value = 'test name';

// ARRAY
$sub->Attributes = array(
    $dadosEXAC1,
);
$ts->Subscribers = array();
$ts->Subscribers = $sub;

// SEND
$ts->TriggeredSendDefinition = $tsd;
$object = new SoapVar($ts, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TriggeredSend', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
$request = new ExactTarget_CreateRequest();
$opts = new ExactTarget_CreateOptions();
$request->Objects = array($object);

// CREATE
$request->Options = $opts;
$response = $client->Create($request);
```

I did not find in the manual where I put the $ clientIDObj-> ClientID